# inheritance issue when base class is defined in python module written in C++ with boost

Tags: python, c++, oop, boost

I am totally new to python, i am trying to understand why inheritance does not work as it should.

I have module written in C++ (using boost) which says the following:

```
 [...]
    class_<Bar::Foo>("Foo")
        .add_property("type", Object_type)
        .add_property("id", &Udm::Object::uniqueId)
 [...]
```

This module is loaded and

then I have another module that says:

```
class X (Bar.Foo)
    def __init__ (self, obj):
        self = obj
    @staticmethod
    def cast(obj):
            return X(obj)
```

Finally in the user code i Have

```
>>> o=dn.root
>>> print o.id
2062344320
```

this is fine, o is a Bar.Foo returned by dn.root

```
>>> rf = X.cast(dn.root)
>>> print rf.id
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
Boost.Python.ArgumentError: Python argument types in
None.None(X)
did not match C++ signature:
None(Bar::Foo {lvalue})
```

I can not understand why rf.id does not work as long as id is a base class member and it was not overloaded in X.

Thanks,
Endre

Comment: Are you sure `self = obj` makes sense in Python?

Comment: dn.root is another call method defined in the C++ python module and returns Bar::Foo C++type:  .add_property("root", &GetRootObject)

Comment: I had to add def __init__(self,obj): self=obj otherwise I was getting errors for this line: X.cast(dn.root), although dn.root is of type Bar.Foo.

Comment: could be the problem that in when I created that the implementation of Bar.Foo.id is on C++ side, and when this is invoked on an object of type X, that type is unknown for the C++ module? (as X was defined only in python, as a derived class of Bar.Foo)?

Comment: just people would understand what I would like to do: There is a C++ python module created with boost which defines Bar.Foo, and then there is a generated X.py, where I would like to create derived class X from Bar.Foo and add extra methods. Is that possible? I have read this [link](https://wiki.python.org/moin/boost.python/Inheritance) and unfortunately this document does not describe the exact scenario that I have.

Comment: `self = obj` does not do what you think it does. `self` is just a local variable, that happens to be bound to the object on which the method was invoked. If you assign to it, it just gets bound to another object. The original object still exists and is not affected by the assignment. Variables in Python are just names that are associated with objects, not references to ranges of bytes in memory like they are in C/C++.

Comment: Also, there is no such thing as a cast in Python, and there are no copy constructors, at least not like there are in C++, and, BTW, `__init__()` is no constructor, it is an initializer (hence the name). When `__init__()` gets called, the object already exists. The closest thing to a constructor in Python is the static method `__new__()`, but it is still something very different from a constructor in C++. You should skim through the [tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/index.html). All we can do at this point is repeating for you what's already written there.